# How to set an Interface as a return type of a web method in a web service

Tags: web-services, soap, interface, xml-serialization, asmx

I am using an interface as a return type of a web method in a webservice.

```
 [WebMethod]
    //[XmlInclude(typeof(BillerConnectAPIStatus))]
    public IBillerConnectAPIStatus PerformInquiry()
    {
        BillerConnectAPIStatus oBillerConnectApitStatue = new BillerConnectAPIStatus();
        return oBillerConnectApitStatue;
    }
```

The Interface is :

```
public interface IBillerConnectAPIStatus 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    int Status { get; set; }
}
```

The class that implements the interface is :

```
   [Serializable]
public class BillerConnectAPIStatus : IBillerConnectAPIStatus
{
    string _description;
    int _status;
//[XmlElement]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }

 //[XmlElement]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
        }
    }
   
    public void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But at run time it gives an error that is:

> Cannot serialize interface Billerconnect_BillerApp_Interfaces.IBillerConnectAPIStatus.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web >request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it >originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize interface Billerconnect_BillerApp_Interfaces.IBillerConnectAPIStatus.

I have applied a [Serializable] attribute on the class that implements the interface as i know i can not serialize an interface.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return an interface because you cannot serialize an interface with XML Serialization.

Comment: Can I use Abstract class to implement same functionality? As i came to know already that i cannot use interfaces

Comment: Web services send XML across the wire. XML is not abstract, it's concrete, so, no, not abstract classes, either. See [Basics: How Web Services Work](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/basics-how-web-services-work/).